# Did Democritus predict atoms using sharp phase transitions

Tags: ancient-greece, atomic-theory, statistical-mechanics

In the Wikipedia page for the Ising Model it is written without citations:

> One of Democritus' arguments in support of atomism was that atoms
> naturally explain the sharp phase boundaries observed in
> materials[citation needed], as when ice melts to water or water turns
> to steam.

My question is:

Is this statement historically accurate? If so, did Democritus have an argument or explained his intuition on how exactly atoms explain sharp phase transitions?

Comment: No and Democritus did not make any arguments about phase transitions. Wikipedia's claims not backed up by citations and missing even details of what is claimed can be safely ignored. Judging by online posts, the 'reasoning' of enthusiasts goes like this: sharp phase transitions are best explained by atoms, Democritus argued for atoms, therefore, Democritus explained sharp phase transitions with atoms.

Comment: All works of Democritus are lost. His theory is known only from the poem of Lucretius who lived much later. So we simply do not know Democritus's own arguments.